# Execute query update in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-4.0

I have a query (`With` and `Update`), I want to execute it when I click refresh, no return should I need to create a new class `Updateprice()` and call it or just write a method in `Main()`. In `Main()` I create an `ExecuteNonQuery()` but I can't push my SQL update in it so I create another connection string in a new class. How to run that SQL command after I click the refresh or save button.

```
public bool ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connInter))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**And here what I tried:**

```
public class Updateprice
{
    public string connInter = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringConn"].ConnectionString;
    public Updateprice()
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connInter))
            {
                SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connInter);
                string query = @" WITH Sales_CTE (PR_KEY, TOTAL_PRICE)
                             AS
                             (
                            SELECT
                                Sale.PR_KEY,
                                SUM(PRICE * AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PRICE
                            FROM
                                Sale_Detail
                            INNER JOIN Sale
                                ON Sale_Detail.FR_KEY = Sale.PR_KEY
                            GROUP BY
                                Sale.PR_KEY, TRAN_ID, TRAN_NO, TRAN_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, USER_ID, TABLE_ID, PAY_TYPE_ID
                            )
                            UPDATE
                                Sale
                            SET
                                Sale.TOTAL_PRICE = Sales_CTE.TOTAL_PRICE
                            FROM
                                Sale
                            INNER JOIN
                                Sales_CTE
                            ON
                                Sales_CTE.PR_KEY = Sale.PR_KEY;";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connect))
                {
                    command.Connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    command.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my sale listing** where I want to show my total price, I succeed to show a table have that column total price, should I call the `updateprice()` in here:

```
public partial class FrmSale_Listing : FrmDataList
{
    public FrmSale_Listing(NHMain nhmain)
        : base(nhmain, "SALE_VIEW")
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }
   
    public override void EditRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            FrmSale f = new FrmSale(NHMain, this.DataSet, "SALE", "SALE_DETAIL", double.Parse(this.GetDataRow()["FR_KEY"].ToString().Replace(",0000", "")))
            {
                isNew = false
            };
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public override void NewRecord()
    {
        FrmSale f = new FrmSale(NHMain, this.DataSet, "SALE", "SALE_DETAIL", true);
        f.isNew = true;
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**My question is**

How to execute the query above without return, is my code correct, should I need to create `SqlConnection` again or just create a string of my SQL command and push it to `public bool ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)`, could anyone show me an example code similar to my issue?

Comment: So whats your question?

Comment: I have corrected my question.

Comment: You definitely **do not** need to open a second connection inside your using block.

Comment: Your UpdatePrice function updates EVERY SINGLE ROW in Sale. Why? Perhaps you intended to Update a single row (or perhaps a small set of rows) in Sale based on some change your application / user just made. If so you should limit the update to the affected rows - not everything that exists in the table.

Comment: Aside from the logic of the update as mentioned, you should just remove `SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connInter);`

Comment: And why would Updateprice (or UpdatePrice - your casing is inconsistent) be a class? To extend that thought, much of your code is inconsistent. EditRecord has a try/catch block while NewRecord does not. The constructor for FrmSale should have the appropriate default for IsNew or should be passed to the Constructor. You have a block just to assign IsNew in EditRecord but not in NewRecord.

Comment: And one last comment about Updateprice - a class constructor should NOT attempt to access/update a database.